# HDA Intel PCH ALC1150 No Sound Ubuntu 14.04x64

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel

I have a new machine running a Gigabyte Z170N-Gaming 5 motherboard with an HDA Intel PCH ALC1150 sound card.  The sound card produces a slight hiss, but I receive no output from the analog line-out.  Muting the card actually mutes the hiss, so I have to believe I'm controlling the correct device.

I've followed other suggestions by adding the following to the end of my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=pch position_fix=1
options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
options snd-hda-intel model=basic
```

and I've put the following into my `~/.asoundrc` (I don't even know if this applies to Ubuntu):

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card PCH
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card PCH
}
```

I've reinstalled pulseaudio, run through alsamixer playing with levels, built the latest alsa-lib from the alsa project, and pretty well exhausted every option I can find.

I even purchased a Turtle Beach Amigo II USB sound card, but that has terrible audio out.

Is there anything left to try?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I updated the title.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily`

Comment: Is there anything I risk by doing this?

Comment: Never mind that.  I was able to find that answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/722023/should-i-upgrade-my-kernel-from-3-16-to-4) among other places.  Giving the kernel upgrade a go...

Comment: Bingo.  Throw your comment up as an answer and I'll award the bounty.  A little explanation for why this works would help future folks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily
```

This will install the new kernel version from Ubuntu 15.10.  For details, see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack